# SQL Server 2008 passing datatype as parameter for function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Since SQL Server 2008 does not have a Try_convert function I wanted to implement it for use in my Project. (no simply updating to a more recent version is not an option)

Problem is: How can i pass a datatype as a parameter to my Function?

Or

More generic: What entry type does a variable need to be to be able to hold a datatype?

Basically I want to build a Function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_Try_Convert
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @value varchar(max),@entrytype type,
    @format int = NULL  
)
RETURNS typeof(@entrytype)
AS
BEGIN
    if @entrytype = typeof(datetime)
        if (select  ISDATE(@value))=1
            return convert(@entrytype,@value,@format)
    if @entrytype = typeof(int)     
        if (select  isnumeric(@value))=1
            return convert(@entrytype,@value,Null)
END
GO
```

What do I need to pass for @entrytypes type and for the typeOf psyodo-function?

Comment: This can't be done in T-SQL like this.  
T-SQL does not have a data type that can hold a data type.

Comment: The other problem here is that the functions like `ISNUMERIC` aren't great. For example try `ISNUMERIC('.')` and then `CONVERT(int,'.')` or `CONVERT(decimal(2,1),'.')`. Notice that both converts fail, but `ISNUMERIC` returns true.

Comment: You'll need to create a CLR function for this to work in your 2008.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is no `TRY_CONVERT()` or `TRY_CAST()` in SQL-Server 2008, but you can use XML's internal casts to nullable types.

Try this

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(SomeInt VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('123')
                      ,('blah') --bad data
SELECT t.*
      ,CAST('' AS XML).value('sql:column("t.SomeInt") cast as xs:int?','int')
FROM @tbl t;
```

Bit of a hack... But somehow beautiful ;-)

### Some explanantion

The `CAST('' AS XML)` is just a trick to get a *real XML* in order to get use of XML's native methods. The `sql:column()` is a `XQuery`-function, which allows you to include a set's column into the `XQuery` (use `sql:variable` for variables).

The `cast as xs:int?` will try to parse the string as int-value and will return NULL if this does not work.

The limit is: This will always use your system's defaults (similar to `TRY_CAST`). With `TRY_CONVERT` you'd have more control over the output with the third paramter...

Hint: `XQuery/Xpath` is strictly case-sensitive. So there is `xs:dateTime?`, but you'd get an error with `xs:datetime`...

Comment: beautiful indeed :-)