# Why ISNumeric() Transact-SQL function treats some var-chars as Int

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT some_column 
FROM some_table 
WHERE some_column = '3.'
```

Return row/rows

```
SELECT some_column 
FROM some_table 
WHERE ISNUMERIC(some_column) = 0 
  AND some_column IS NOT NULL 
  AND some_column <> ''
```

Does not return any non numeric row/rows. there is a row which has a column value of '3.'

Am i missing something. Please Advise.

Comment: Can you provide an example on https://dbfiddle.uk/ or http://sqlfiddle.com/?

Comment: Is this `[sql-server]`? (Please tag accordingly) And which version? (Please tag accordingly). `ISNUMERIC` is quite ancient and well known for some rather weird values. There are better approaches... And read [mcve]. Please try to set up a *stand-alone* sample with test data and expected output.

Comment: Considering you *hopefully* are using SQL Server 2012+ (if you are still using 2008 you're very close to running completely out of support) I suggest using `TRY_CONVERT` or `TRY_CAST`. For example, instead of `ISNUMERIC('.') = 1` use `TRY_CONVERT(int, '.') IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: If you are still on a version below 2012, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53279357/5089204) provides a good workaround to simulate `TRY_CAST()` using a XML-hack.

Comment: [`IsNumeric()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql) is notoriously [problematic](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/ISNUMERIC()/71512/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ISNUMERIC()` has some flaws. It can return True/1 for values that are clearly not numbers.

```
SELECT 
ISNUMERIC('.'), 
ISNUMERIC('$')
```

If this is causing you issues, try using `TRY_PARSE()`

```
SELECT 
TRY_PARSE('2' AS INT)
```

You can use this and filter for non-null results.

```
SELECT some_column 
FROM some_table 
WHERE TRY_PARSE(some_column AS INT) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm working on 2008 SP1 which apparently doesnt support this function. smh

Comment: Good answer. Note, however that SELECT TRY_PARSE('3.' AS INT) will return 3 which means this solution might not work. `TRY_CAST` or `TRY_CONVERT` might be better perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand the question.  `ISNUMERIC('3.')` returns `1`.  So it would not be returned by the second query.  And, presumably, no other rows would either.

Perhaps you really intend:  `somecolumn not like '%[^0-9]%'`.  This will guarantee that `somecolumn` has only the digits from 0-9.

In SQL Server 2012+, you can also use `try_convert(int, somecolumn) is not null`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
So the table has more than 50K rows and the column I'm interested in should only accept INT value but somehow a few non-integer values ended up in the column which now causing the issue in Data Mapping. I'm trying to comb through the column to get all non-numeric values.  ISNumeric(some_column) = 0 or ISNumeric(some_column) <> 1 should return desired result.

Answer (score 0):

ISNUMERIC is a legacy function, I would don't like it personally. It does exactly what it's supposed to do which is usually not what you need ("Is Numeric" is a very subjective question in Computer Science.) I recently wrote this query to clarify things for some co-workers:

```
SELECT string = x, [isnumeric says...] = ISNUMERIC(x) 
FROM (VALUES ('1,2,3,,'),(',,,,,,,,,,'),(N'﹩'),(N'＄'),(N'￠'),('12,0'),(N'52,3,1.25'),
             (N'-4,1'),(N'56.'),(N'5D105'),('1E1'),('\4'),(''),(N'\'),(N'₤'),(N'€')) x(x);
```

**Returns:**

```
string     isnumeric says...
---------- -----------------
1,2,3,,    1
,,,,,,,,,, 1
﹩         0
＄         1
￠         0
12,0       1
52,3,1.25  1
-4,1       1
56.        1
5D105      1
1E1        1
\4         1
           0
\          1
₤          1
€          1
```

TRY_CAST or TRY_CONVERT, or `WHERE somecolumn not like '%[^0-9]%'` as Gordon said, could be a good alternative.

For performance reasons it might not be a bad idea to pre-aggregate, persist and index the column by adding a new computed column. E.g. something like

```
ALTER <your table> 
ADD isGoodNumber AS (ABS(SIGN(PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',<your column>))-1)
```

This would return a 1 for rows only containing digits or a 0 otherwise. You can then index isGoodNumber (you pick a better name) for better performance.